# Is "leaning" not a verb?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

Please see the following sentence:

> Detaching itself from the main body of traffic, a lone auto-rickshaw drew up near Porus, the driver **leaning** out expectantly.

Looking at http://tfd.com/leaning I can see it only as a noun and an adjective but not a verb.

Is this not a verb in this sentence?

Comment: In most simple terms, *leaning* is a verb *form*, like "leaned" or "leans", and most dictionaries won't have a separate entry on those. You should check the main entry, "lean".

Answer (score 3):

It's a verb, but a non-finite one, like *detaching* at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: non finite verb is different from in-transitive verb ?

Comment: @poorenglish: No, a non-finite verb is one that is not marked for tense or person.

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? "not marked for tense" means ?

Comment: @poorenglish: A form like 'walks' tells us that the person walking is neither you nor me, but someone else, referred to in grammatical terms as 'third person'. It also tells us that the verb is in the present tense. That's why we say it's marked for tense and person. A form like 'walking', on the other hand, tells us nothing about tense or person, so it's not marked for these. (If you have difficulty with these concepts, you need to consult a grammar book or an English teacher. You can't expect to fully understand them from a few comments here, unfortunately.)